# ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse, all packages are in the same src folder

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm working on a calculator program that works from the console, which is also supposed to support creating inline functions, e.g. `inline _FOO{a1, a2} a1 + a2` declares the function and calling `_FOO{2,3}` should return 2+3. I'm using a Converter class to do all the parsing and calculations. 
I created a class called InlineFunction in the same package that holds the implementations of the programs default functions, which all work fine, but when trying to call an inline function I get an error.
When debugging I noticed that when the program works fine up until the part where I actually declare a new Inline Function, `InlineFunction function = new InlineFunction();` I immediately get a ClassNotFoundException. I can't figure out why, because that function is in the same package as the other, working, functions, and I import the entire package in the Converter class.

EDIT: The code for InlineFunction:

```
package oop.ex2.functions;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import oop.ex2.main.UndeclaredVariableException;

public class InlineFunction implements Calculable {
    //Regular expression for finding a variable name.
    private static final String VARIABLE_NAME_REGEX = "@[a-z0-9]+";
    //Pattern for finding a variable name.
    private static final Pattern VARIABLE_NAME = Pattern.compile(VARIABLE_NAME_REGEX);
    private LinkedHashMap<String, Double> _parameters;
    private String _code;

    public InlineFunction(String code, String[] parameters) {
        _parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
        _code = code;
        for (String name: parameters) {
            _parameters.put(name, 0d);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String calculate(Double[] parameters) {
        if (parameters.length != _parameters.size()) {
            throw new IllegalParameterNumberException();
        }
        int parameterIndex = 0;
        for (String key: _parameters.keySet()){
            _parameters.put(key, parameters[parameterIndex]);
        }
        _code = replaceParameters(_code);
        return _code;
    }

    private String replaceParameters(String expression) {
        Matcher variableName = VARIABLE_NAME.matcher(expression);
        while (variableName.find()) {
            if (_parameters.containsKey(variableName.group())) {
                expression = variableName.replaceFirst(_parameters.get(variableName.group()).toString());
                //Reset the matcher, since the expression was changed
                variableName = VARIABLE_NAME.matcher(expression);
            } else {
                throw new UndeclaredVariableException();
            }
        }
        return expression;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your definition of InlineFunction?

Comment: is there any reason why your code would not compile? Did you check the output folder?

Comment: There is no output folder, the output is directly to the console, but there is an InlineFunction.class file in the bin folder, so the code compiles

Comment: Are you working on an Eclipse application or a full Java only application ? How do you launch your application ?

Comment: The problem was due to not handling the input given to the constructor properly, and has been fixed. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Since you find out the solution, please close this question. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to not handling the input given to the constructor properly, and has been fixed.